# How have I computed the integral $\int \sin^{3}(3x)\cos(3x)\,dx$ incorrectly?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$\displaystyle \int \sin^{3}(3x)\cos(3x)\,dx $

$u = 3x  $

$du = 3\,dx  $

$3\displaystyle\int \sin^{3}(u)\cos(u)\,du$

$3\displaystyle\int \sin^{2}(u)\sin(u)\cos(u)\,du$

$3\displaystyle\int (1 - \cos^{2}(u))\sin(u)\cos(u)\,du$

$v = \cos(u)$

$dv = -\sin(u)\,du  $

$3\displaystyle\int (1 - v^{2})(-1)v\,dv$

$ 3\displaystyle\int (-v + v^{3})\,dv$

$ 3\left[-\frac{v^{2}}{2} + \frac{v^{4}}{4}\right]$

$3\left[ -\frac{\cos^{3}{3x}}{2} + \frac{\cos^{4}(3x)}{4}\right] $

$= -3 \frac{\cos^{2}(3x)}{2} + 3\frac{\cos^{4}(3x)}{4} + C$

wolfram states this as incorrect, what have I done wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You determined $du=3\,dx$, but substituted $dx = 3\,du$.  So your answer is off by a factor of nine.
$$
\int \sin^3(3x) \cos(3x)\,dx = \int \sin^3(u) \cos(u)\cdot \frac{1}{3}\,du
= \frac{1}{3}\int \sin^3(u) \cos(u)\,du
$$
Then proceed as you did.  You'll get 
$$
\int \sin^3(3x) \cos(3x)\,dx =- \frac{1}{6} \cos^2(3x) -\frac{1}{12}\cos^4(3x)+C
$$

The other answers are suggesting substituting $u=\sin(3x)$ in one fell swoop.  Then $du = 3 \cos(3x)\,dx$, so
$$
\int \sin^3(3x) \cos(3x)\,dx = \frac{1}{3}\int u^3\,du = \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{4}u^4 + C = \frac{1}{12}\sin^4(3x)+C
$$
Both are correct, although the second solution is more compact and concise.  In the comments you asked if the two are “equivalent.” Yes, but only in the antiderivative sense.  Using the trig identities:
\begin{align*}
    - \frac{1}{6}\cos^2(3x) + \frac{1}{12}\cos^4(3x)
    &= \frac{1}{12}\cos^2(3x)\left(\cos^2(3x) - 2\right) \\
    &= \frac{1}{12}\left(1-\sin^2(3x)\right)\left(1-\sin^2(3x)-2\right) \\
    &= \frac{1}{12}\left(1-\sin^2(3x)\right)\left(-1-\sin^2(3x)\right) \\
    &= \frac{1}{12}\left(\sin^2(3x)-1\right)\left(\sin^2(3x)+1\right) \\
    &= \frac{1}{12}\left(\sin^4(3x)-1\right) = \frac{1}{12}\sin^4(3x) - \frac{1}{12}
\end{align*}
You can see the two antiderivatives differ by a constant.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I did that and got: -cos(3x) / 3 + cos^4(3x) / 12 + C

Comment: @yre: I think you'd get $-\cos^2(3x)/6 + \cos^4(3x)/12 + C$; that's 1/9 times what you got the first time.

Comment: Oh right! I see. Is this equivalent to 1/12sin^4(3x) + C ?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Why are you making things complicated unnecessarily

Just set  $\sin ax=u$  for $$\int\sin^max\cos^{2n+1}ax\ dx$$

Comment: Thank you
I am not sure I know what you mean.

Comment: Suppose you meant $u=\sin(ax)$ :)

Comment: @yre, Have u tried following my method?

Comment: @SpettroDiA, Thanks

Comment: Who's making things complicated unnecessarily?  The novice integrator, or the guy inserting new variables $m$, $n$, and $a$ into the problem?

Comment: @Matthew, Have u understood the generalization?

Comment: Yes, but as you can tell by the first comment the OP does not.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is $dx = \frac 13 du$. So instead multiplying by $3$, multiply by $\frac13$.

Alternative -

I think if you put $\cos 3x$ as $u$. That is much easy to solve.

Comment: If you have any doubt please ask.